# Map data from one multidimensional array to another based on shared id value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping

Here are two example of the format of the Arrays, full code and array content in my code below.

ARRAY 1

```
[
    'version' => '1.0',
    'injuries' => [
        'timestamp' => 1377702112,
        'week' => 1,
        'injury' => [
            [
                'status' => 'Questionable',
                'id' => '10009',
                'details' => 'Shoulder'
            ],
            [
                'status' => 'Questionable',
                'id' => '10012',
                'details' => 'Ankle'
            ]
        ]
    ]    
]
```

ARRAY 2

```
[
    'version' => '1.0',
    'players' => [
        'timestamp' => 1377676937,
        'player' => [
            [
                'position' => 'TMDL',
                'name' => 'Bills, Buffalo',
                'id' => '0251',
                'team' => 'BUF'
            ],
            [
                'position' => 'TMDL',
                'name' => 'Colts, Indianapolis',
                'id' => '10009',
                'team' => 'IND'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

What I need to do is sort through both Arrays and finding matching values for the ID key. I need to then combine the values of both arrays into one array so I can print it out on screen. There is two API's provided, one for the injuries report with a player [id] key and the other for the Players Information with [id] keys. Here is how far I have gotten on this problem:

```
<?php
 
       function injuries_report() {         
       
       //Get json files
       
         $injuryData = file_get_contents('http://football.myfa...=1&callback=');
         $playerData = file_get_contents('http://football.myfa...L=&W=&JSON=1');
         
       //format json data into an array
       
          $obj1 = json_decode($injuryData, true);
         $obj2 = json_decode($playerData, true);
 
       
 
         //return print_r($obj1);   //print obj1 to see output
         
         return print_r($obj2);     //print obj2 to see output
 
       }
 
      ?> 
 
       <!--get injuries report -->
 
      <pre><?php injuries_report(); ?></pre>
```

Here's the working code, thanks to Chris:)

```
$injuryData = file_get_contents('http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export?TYPE=injuries&L=&W=&JSON=1&callback=');
    $array1 = json_decode($injuryData, true);
    $playerData = file_get_contents('http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export?TYPE=players&L=&W=&JSON=1');
    $array2 = json_decode($playerData, true);
     
    function map($x) {
       global $array1;
       if(isset($x['id'])) {
          $id = $x['id'];
          $valid = array_filter($array1['injuries']['injury'], create_function('$injury', 'return $injury["id"] == "' . $id .'";'));
          if(count($valid) > 0) {
             $x = array_merge($x, array_shift($valid));
          }
           }
           return $x;
        }
        $output = array_map('map', $array2['players']['player']);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($output);
        echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Show how result array should look like.

Comment: Do you want to print all players and print injuries if the have any, or do you only want to print out injured players?

Comment: I need a new array with the matching ID's players [name] key that shows the full name of the team. This is a sports injuries API so I want to show all injured players.  The actual plaers name is in another API call that looks like this: http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2012/export?TYPE=players&PLAYERS=10067&JSON=1   I'll need to do something here: &players=[Id key goes here]   my brain hurts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm assuming you want to add injuries to players. The output will be the list of players, with the injuries added (where they apply)

```
$output = array_map(function($x) use ($array1) {
   $id = $x['id'];
   $valid = array_filter($array1['injuries']['injury'], function($injury) use ($id) {
      return $injury['id'] == $id;
   });
   if(count($valid) > 0) {
      $x = array_merge($x, $valid[0]);
   }
   return $x;
}, $array2['players']['player']);

print_r($output);
```

The output is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [position] => TMDL
            [name] => Bills, Buffalo
            [id] => 0251
            [team] => BUF
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [position] => TMDL
            [name] => Colts, Indianapolis
            [id] => 10009
            [team] => IND
            [status] => Questionable
            [details] => Shoulder
        )
)
```

---

## php 5.2

**Edit** The latest working version:

Oh you are using php 5.2. Here is a php 5.2 version, but it less pretty than the code before:

```
$injuryData = file_get_contents('http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export?TYPE=injuries&L=&W=&JSON=1&callback=');
$array1 = json_decode($injuryData, true);
$playerData = file_get_contents('http://football.myfantasyleague.com/2013/export?TYPE=players&L=&W=&JSON=1');
$array2 = json_decode($playerData, true);

function map($x) {
   global $array1;
   if(isset($x['id'])) {
      $id = $x['id'];
      $valid = array_filter($array1['injuries']['injury'], create_function('$injury', 'return $injury["id"] == "' . $id .'";'));
      if(count($valid) > 0) {
         $x = array_merge($x, array_shift($valid));
      }
   }
   return $x;
}
$output = array_map('map', $array2['players']['player']);
print_r($output);
```

The `$array1` is global here. Check it here: http://pastebin.com/N3RqtfzN

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /home4/bags/public_html/wp-content/themes/fantasy/page.php on line 17   Not sure if this is it or not but line 17 is the first line of code. My server is running Php 5.2, is there a way to do it without an anonymous function? Im not sure what Im missing here, the code looks good, I have it just like you wrote it but not working:(

Comment: @MichaelHicks It's a shame you are using php 5.2, but anyway, I have created a php 5.2 compatible version. Please check it.

Comment: I dont get it. Heres what I get when I combine everything: http://codepad.org/fD2ym6Yo   Also when I try it on mky website I get this error:   Warning:  array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The first argument should be an array in /home4/bags/public_html/wp-content/themes/fantasy/page.php on line 16

Comment: You used the C option instead of the php one.

Comment: anyway, try this one: http://pastebin.com/hKuJvWPQ (I didn't used codepad.org here, since it seems it does not like the `file_get_contents` command)

Comment: I fixed it but still no luck.

Comment: View it here: http://fantasyaficionado.com/nfl/ This is what I get, its better but its not showing the details key that states the injury.

Comment: Try this one: http://pastebin.com/N3RqtfzN it works ok for me. To see the merge, for instance,  check number `[483]`, which has `details` =`Shoulder`

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. If this answer was useful, can you select it as accepted answer? is done like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: Yeah but post the final code on top of your first code so people know which one it is. Thanks again:)